# How to know if a tree is colorable

Tags: tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

I cannot understand why the following RB tree is not colorable.
[image: RBtree]

I thought the only requirement was:

> The path from the root to the farthest leaf is no more than twice as long as the path from the root to the nearest leaf.

But in the image you can see the shortest path (orange) is 2 and the longest path (blue) is 4, which means it should be colorable according to the rule above.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it is colorable. A red Black tree must always follow these rules:

- Every node has a color either red or black.
- Root of tree is always black.
- There are no two adjacent red nodes (A red node cannot have a red parent or red child).
- Every path from root to a NULL node has same number of black nodes.

The tree can not be colored because both 2-blue and 3-blue should be red, which violates the 3 rule.

> The path from the root to the farthest leaf is no more than twice as
>   long as the path from the root to the nearest leaf.

This is not exactly a requirement, but a generic property of RB Trees. skipping the mathematical proof, consider a tree where on one branch you have only black nodes, while on the other branch red and black nodes alternate. In this situation you have the maximum unbalance, if it was not like that at least one of the above rules are violated.

Theoretically you have 2 types of height in a RB Tree:

- *Black Height*, which is common to all branches in your tree (otherwise 4 rule is violated)
- *"Total Height"* (it is not an existing term), which is the maximum number of red nodes + black nodes on a single path from root to NIL.

Comment: Every path from root to a NULL node has same number of black nodes - this rule is not respected in your example. You have bh(1) and also bh(2) on the root

Comment: oops. Thanks, did not notice

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to count NILs. That way the shortest path is 1 and the longest path is 3, which means the rule you quoted is applicable because twice the path from the root to the nearest leaf is 1*2 and 3 (the actual longest path) is greater => not colorable.